# Append string to specific records in specific fields

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have a file that looks like

```
No. 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 0 1 0 1
5 0 0 0 0 0
7 1 1 1 0 1
8 0 1 1 0 1
9 1 1 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 1 0 1
```

I want to append a text, lets say var in front of all the items in first row except the first few (lets say 2, this number varies) such that my file looks like

```
No. 1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1 1 0 1 0 1
5 0 0 0 0 0
7 1 1 1 0 1
8 0 1 1 0 1
9 1 1 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 1 0 1
```

I tried using awk with the statement

```
awk '{ if(NR==1) for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
 print  "var"$i; 
  for (j = 2; j <= NR; j++) print $0 }' input
```

But I didn't get the expected result. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {$i = "var" $i}}1' File
```

**Logic:**

```
`NR==1` => If Line 1, from 3rd field (`i=3`) to end of line (`i=NF`), change `i`th field to `varith field`.
```

**Example:**

```
~$ cat File
No. 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 0 1 0 1
5 0 0 0 0 0
7 1 1 1 0 1
8 0 1 1 0 1
9 1 1 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 1 0 1
~$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {$i = "var" $i}}1' File
No. 1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1 1 0 1 0 1
5 0 0 0 0 0
7 1 1 1 0 1
8 0 1 1 0 1
9 1 1 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 1 0 1
```

You can change value of `i` as per your need.

Comment: `awk 'NR==1{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {$i = "var" $i}}1' File` and `awk 1 *.xml` can you please tell me why we need the '1' in these two command? The last one works like `cat *.xml`

Comment: @zhujs: It is used here to print all the records, even the unaffected ones... Take a look here: http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ , u'll understand better.

Comment: @A.M.D how can I change labels differently now. From 2 to 5 as "Patient 2" .. and from 6 to end as "Pat 6". awk 'NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {{if ($i <= 5) $i = "Patient " $i; else $i="Pa " $i;}}}1' file didn't quite work. Thanks.

Comment: Can u show the overall expected output? If i understood u correctly, this shud work for u: awk 'NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {{if (i <= 5) $i = "Patient " $i; else $i="Pa " $i;}}}1'

Answer (score 3):

try this line:

```
awk -v val=2 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=($i>=val?"var"$i:$i)}7' file
```

change the variable `val=2` with the desired value.